# Merging/appending multiple pcap files to an existing one without overwriting

Tags: wireshark, libpcap, tcpdump, tshark

I am using tshark to filter some packets based on Display/Read filters from one file into another.

I want to have one final output file out.pcap after executing multiple read filters over number of  files and combine all into out.pcap.

I was trying to use mergecap but it does not allow to append (combine) two file and store in one of them without overwriting.

Is there any way to do this, as I don't want to keep creating temporary files and merge all them together at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible that I know of with existing tools, although given the way the capture file format is layed out, it should be possible to write a new tool (or extend mergecap) to do this.

Comment: Any suggestions on approach for modifying mergecap or tshark?

Comment: Not my area of expertise, sorry. I would ask on the wireshark-dev mailing list (https://www.wireshark.org/lists/).

Answer (score 0):

Do this in bash:

```
for file
  in *.pcap;
do
  echo "$file";
  tshark -r "$file" -Y "ip.addr == 8.8.8.8 or ip.addr == 1.1.1.1" -w /tmp/out_$file.pcap;
done
```

It will read all the pcap files under the current folder and write the out_$file.pcap under /tmp. You can change the filter ("`ip.addr == 8.8.8.8 or ip.addr == 1.1.1.1`") as per your needs.

Then you use mergercap to merger all the outfiles:

```
mergecap /tmp/out_*.pcp -w out.pcap
rm /tmp/out_*.pcap
```